# Visual Studio ReSharper - Typescript automatic import class declared in external module - Use from instead of require

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017, resharper

When using JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2018.3.4 and using the command `Import 'class '' declared in external module ''' and all other types` it uses `require` for import. This works but I would like it to use `from` instead like Visual Studio normally does. How can this be enabled?

Generated code from ReSharper:

```
import Requests = require("../../../requests");
import ApiPaths = Requests.ApiPaths;
```

[image]

Generated code from standard Visual Studio 2017 Professional:

```
import { ApiPaths } from '../../../requests';
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ReSharper Options, navigate to Code Editing -> TypeScript -> Code Style -> Aliases

For 'Preferred import statement kind (if possible)', choose 'ES6-style imports'.